# Permitir que apenas digitem 123456 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou estudando Jquery e me deparei com uma atividade de lógica, preciso permitir que o usuário apenas posso digitar as teclas 123456 no input.

código html:

```
 <h3>Teclado</h3>
    <span>Nome:</span>
    <input type="text" id="teclado" />
    <span id="resultadoTecla">Resultado do evento sobre o input</span>
```

cógido jquery/javascript

```
            $('#teclado').keyup((e) => {
                if(e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 102){                        
                    var number = $(e.target).val();
                    $(e.target).val(number);
                    console.log('log 1: ' + number);
                } else {

                } 
            })
```

Eu comecei a lógica, porém não sei como impedir outros valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia é permitir apenas dígitos de 1 a 6 no input, eu evitaria essa abordagem de verificar a tecla digitada, ela possui falhas como:

- O usuário pode clicar com o mouse e colar um texto no input, o qual não passaria pela validação.
- O usuário pode utilizar atalhos no teclado, o que também pode ou não ser indevidamente validado.
- O usuário pode acessar o site pelo celular, o qual produz `keyCode` diferentes ao inserir os caracteres.

A solução mais segura seria provavelmente utilizar uma `máscara`. Você também pode formatar o valor do `input` sempre que ele for alterado, de forma a deletar todos os caracteres inválidos, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$('#teclado').on('input', (evt) => {
    evt.target.value = evt.target.value.replace(/[^1-6]/g, '')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="teclado"/>
```

Comment: Agradeço pela sua explicação, me ajudou bastante, era realmente algo assim que eu buscava, agora preciso estudar um pouco mais de JS para saber como utilizar corretamente o replace.

Answer (score 0):

Isto pode ser alcançado basicamente sem a necessidade de JS, você pode usar o atributo `pattern`:

```html
<form action="#">
  <input pattern="[1-6]+" type="text" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

Se quiser que a validação ocorra "em tempo real", sem ser somente no momento do *submit*, poderia fazer:

```js
window.document.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  if (!e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement || !e.target.form instanceof HTMLFormElement) {
    return
  }
   
  e.target.form.reportValidity()
}, true);
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input pattern="[1-6]+" title="Digite caracteres numéricos entre 1 e 6" type="text" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

A ideia deste código é bem simples, qualquer mudança em qualquer input irá notificar de erros em todo o formulário.

Comment: +1 pelo `pattern`, mas acho que não é isso que ele quer.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta, nunca tinha ouvido falar sobre pattern, estou realizando um curso básico de Jquery e o professor não comentou sobre isso, irei dar uma melhor estudada no assunto.